# Typo3 7.6 extbase repository matching only affect non-localized records

Tags: localization, repository, matching, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I want to create an own extbase extension for TYPO3 CMS 7.6. The extension has to run in different languages. I figured out, that the repository matching does only work for me with non-localized records.

My repository function looks like that:

```
public function findNew() {
  $query = $this->createQuery();
  $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(true);
  $query->matching($query->equals('new', 1));
  return $query->execute();
}
```

This function says: Show all records with new = 1

Example: 
I have a default record that has the checkbox "New" NOT activated. Now I create a localized version of this record and set the "New" checkbox to activated.

If I execute the function findNew() in the default language, the record will not show up. If I execute the function in another language, the record will also not show up although the "New"-flag is set!

In other words: The matching does only affect the default/parent record.

I'm using the following config-settings:

```
config {
  sys_language_mode = strict
  sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
}
```

[Edit:]
Here's the complete generated SQL query:

```
SELECT tx_extension_domain_model_table.*
FROM
tx_extension_domain_model_table
WHERE
  tx_extension_domain_model_table.new = '1'
  AND (
    tx_extension_domain_model_table.sys_language_uid = -1
    OR (
      tx_extension_domain_model_table.sys_language_uid = 1
      AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.l10n_parent = 0
    )
    OR (
      tx_extension_domain_model_table.sys_language_uid = 0
      AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.uid IN (
        SELECT tx_extension_domain_model_table.l10n_parent
        FROM tx_extension_domain_model_table
        WHERE tx_extension_domain_model_table.l10n_parent > 0
          AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.sys_language_uid = 1
          AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.deleted = 0
      )
    )
  )
  AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.deleted = 0
  AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.t3ver_state <= 0
  AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.pid <> -1
  AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.hidden = 0
  AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.starttime <= 1459780380
  AND (tx_extension_domain_model_table.endtime = 0 OR     tx_extension_domain_model_table.endtime > 1459780380)
ORDER BY tx_extension_domain_model_table.sorting ASC
```

...and the important part:

```
    AND (
        tx_extension_domain_model_table.sys_language_uid = -1
    OR (
      tx_extension_domain_model_table.sys_language_uid = 1
      AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.l10n_parent = 0
    )
    OR (
      tx_extension_domain_model_table.sys_language_uid = 0
      AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.uid IN (
        SELECT tx_extension_domain_model_table.l10n_parent
        FROM tx_extension_domain_model_table
        WHERE tx_extension_domain_model_table.l10n_parent > 0
          AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.sys_language_uid = 1
          AND tx_extension_domain_model_table.deleted = 0
      )
    )
  )
```

That explains my problem. TYPO3 is not looking for new = 1 in sys_language_uid = 1 when it's localized... but why?

Question: Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in extbase, see here for more information: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57272